# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

what does this error mean in my case?

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()'

PS: I'm getting the error in the line when I call Form2.Close()

here is my code:

```
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
    bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.ShowDialog();
    private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        object result = e.Result;
        Form2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for class and object have the same name? `Form2 Form2 = new Form2();`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify an instance of Form2 in a method and want to use it in another method. When you specify an instance in one method it's not available in other methods because it's out of scope. You have to put your Form2 instance e.g. in a private field of your class if both methods are in the same class.

Comment: how can I define a private field?? you mean a private attribute? no?

Comment: Something like private Form2 _myForm;

Answer (score -1):

Change the variable name.
Variable name shouldn't have same name as name Class (Form2)

```
Form2 _myForm = new Form2();
_myForm.Close();
```

Comment: That won't help because it's still out of scope in the method bg_RunWorkerCompleted